# Populate fields in a Word document pre-load?

Tags: microsoft-word

From what I have researched using command switches does not seem possible. Any suggestions on how to populate custom text fields in a Word document or template before firing up the Word UI.

The values will be pre-defined in an application that calls the a Word template from the local network.

Answer (score 1):

It requires code. There are two basic possibilities that do not require the Word object model:

1. Use the .docx format, and use a library such as the Open Office API
   to modify the XML code of the document directly.
2. Use the .docformat, and use dsofile.dll to update the values of Custom Document properties.

(option 2 may work with .docx, but even if it does, suffers from some disadvantages: it only works on Windows; it's an old method; it requires you to distribute dsofile.dll; your data will need to be inserted using DOCPROPERTY fields, which will still need to be updated after the document opens. There is more about dsofile [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/224351)

For option 1, you could use field codes of some kind and update their values directly in the XML, but it is probably simpler to use Content Controls mapped to Custom XML Parts that contain all the data. Then, all you really need to do is replace the XML in the Part with the data appropriate for the document. You may find Eric White's pages (e.g. [starting here](http://ericwhite.com/blog/content-controls-expanded/) ) useful.

Comment: I meant to ask whether you had tried the command line option to run a macro - I think to do that successfully, your application would at least have to put the values somewhere that VBA code could access.

Comment: I haven't tried that, but might be an option. I like the idea of using Open Office and have been researching. Looks like a decent API. Thanks again for your input! I cannot up vote your answer sadly as I need more rep

Comment: Good luck with the O-O approach - I don't know its API so you are already ahead of me on that front. AIUI if you think my "Answer" does in fact answer your question, you should be able to mark it as the Answer regardless of your rep.